Künneth formula for Lie algebra cohomology with coefficients in a nontrivial module
Is there a Künneth formula for Lie algebra cohomology with coefficients in the tensor product of two modules?
Suppose $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$ are two Lie algebras. Let $M_1$ be a $\mathfrak{g}_1$-module and $M_2$ a $\mathfrak{g}_2$-module. Is it true that the Künneth formula $H^k(\mathfrak{g}_1 \times \mathfrak{g}_2, M_1 \otimes M_2) \cong \sum_{i=0}^k H^i(\mathfrak{g}_1, M_1) \otimes H^{k-i}(\mathfrak{g}_2, M_2)$ holds?
Previous questions have asked about the trivial module and the adjoint module but I'm wondering if it is true in a more general setting.

The Künneth formula here comes from de Rham cohomology, which corresponds to Lie algebra cohomology with trivial coefficients. For the cohomology with coefficients in non-trivial modules, such a formula does not hold, I think.

@DietrichBurde It can come from the various algebraic Kunneth / UCT formulas as well, once you make the shift from Lie algebra cohomology to Ext groups over Ug-modules. But as I remember we need trivial modules for that too

@FShrike Do you know why this approach works for trivial modules but not other modules? I'm having trouble seeing where the trivial modules are specifically used

I haven't sat down and looked at / written a full proof in the trivial-module case. If you have one that's not too hard to write up or post a picture of, that would be good. But I could well believe that we need trivial modules. These universal coefficient type theorems typically require assumptions on the base ring, and $U\mathfrak{g}$ could be arbitrarily bad; lowering all homs to the level of $k$-homomorphisms, $k$ a PID (say) would help a lot... but is probably only feasible in the case of trivial modules
